# UIViewController with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, rubymotion

I'm trying to change a UIViewControllers view to a scroll view to make use :

```
def loadView
  super
  scrollView = UIScrollView.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
  self.view = scrollView
  # Tried experimenting with this
  # self.view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width,, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height)
  self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor
end
```

I then add subViews to `self.view` inside of `viewDidLoad`, use `subview.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` on each and then set constraints using `NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat`.

The constraints work fine normally, but as soon as I change the view to a scroll view, everything gets messed up:

[image]

The "title" field should be flush with the navigation bar, and both fields should fill the screen width.

The red box is simply demonstrating the width of the subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's hard to get UIViews working with autoLayout inside of a UIScrollView. What i do in those cases is set a containerView that fills the UIScrollView four edges with constraints and positioning in autoLayout. Then in this container i add what i want, one thing that i always have to do is to keep track of the height of this container and make it grow accordingly to the subviews added to that. This way is a bit harder to implement the view hierarchy, but the constraints become more organized. 
Here is a note from Apple of how to do this in a quick way: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html